# Powershell documentation site root

Tags: powershell, msdn, technet

I found a page of Powershell documentation dated 2010 written for Powershell version 2.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315303.aspx

That page is for a particular command. Where can I read the rest of the documentation for version 2? The left sidebar just shows 'TechNet Library' and has no Powershell links.

---

I found docs for Powershell Version 1 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848793

and pre-release docs for version 3 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-release Windows PowerShell 3.0 documentation covers both Windows PowerShell 2.0 and 3.0. New cmdlets and parameters, and new behavior, are clearly marked. This is really obvious in a help topic for a cmdlet like Get-Command which changed significantly between 2.0 and 3.0.

We're adding an "Applies To" field at the topic of every page to show which versions of Windows PowerShell are covered in each topic.

I thought this was more convenient than having to go to two different doc sets and compare them. Let me know if this works for you!

Thanks,
June

June Blender [MSFT]
Senior Programming Writer
Windows PowerShell
Blog: http://blogs.msdn.com/PowerShell
Twitter: @juneb_get_help

Answer (score 1):

In v2, you can get the help for any given cmdlet using Get-Help -Online parameter:

```
Get-Help <cmdletName> -Online
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I get the front page?

Comment: This opens pre-release documentation for me.

Comment: It does if you're using v3 :)

Comment: `(get-host).version` gives me `Major Minor Build Revision 2 0 -1 -1` so I think I have version 2, however it's installed at `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` which suggests it's version 1.

Comment: Common gotcha, even v3 is installed in v1 folder. Anyway, which command opens a pre-release doc?

Comment: `get-Help out-file -online` opens http://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849882.aspx "Updated: February 15, 2012 [This topic is pre-release documentation.." . I expected it to open http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315303.aspx "Updated: April 21, 2010 Applies To: Windows PowerShell 2.0"